# My Samsung tablel 1 is not restarting?

Tags: applications, boot, reboot

It stop working in process of restarting where android symbol is coming. So what should I have to do for resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ugh...I have been researching this problem too my friends. I have the galaxy tab 7.0 and it has that stupid market instead of play store. While reading, i noticed this happens quite a bit. From what i have seen a hard reset doesn't always do the trick, good luck, sorry i couldnt be more help. I am interested in this solution myself.